# Return previous value before null value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017

I'm currently querying a table with missing indexes.

Here is some sample data:

```
id  dStartDate
126 2010-04-22 00:00:00.000
127 NULL
128 2010-04-29 00:00:00.000
129 2010-05-03 00:00:00.000
130 NULL
131 NULL
132 NULL
133 2010-04-29 00:00:00.000
134 NULL
135 NULL
136 2010-04-29 00:00:00.000
137 NULL
138 NULL
139 2010-04-29 00:00:00.000
140 NULL
141 2010-04-29 00:00:00.000
142 2010-04-29 00:00:00.000
143 NULL
144 NULL
```

I use the following script to get the missing indexes:

```
declare @id int
declare @maxid int

set @id = 1
select @maxid = max(idJCMaster) from _btblJCMaster

declare @IDseq table    (id int)

while @id < @maxid --whatever you max is
begin
    insert into @IDseq values(@id)

    set @id = @id + 1
end

select 
    s.id
from        @IDseq s 
left join   _btblJCMaster t on s.id = t.idJCMaster
where t.idJCMaster is null
```

The above works perfect, however, I would like to see the previous record (that is not null) date, to have an idea when this record was deleted...

I altered the above script to look like this:

```
declare @id int
declare @maxid int

set @id = 1
select @maxid = max(idJCMaster) from _btblJCMaster

declare @IDseq table    (id int)

while @id < @maxid --whatever you max is
begin
    insert into @IDseq values(@id)

    set @id = @id + 1
end

select 
    s.id
,   t.dStartDate
from        @IDseq s 
left join   _btblJCMaster t on s.id = t.idJCMaster
```

The results I get looks like this:

[image: Script 2 Results]

As can be seen, sometimes there is more than on record missing for those particular indexes...

I'm not really sure how to alter the script to show me the previous date (before null).

In this example, my expected results would be:

[image: Expected Results]

Please assist with the expected results?

Your assistance will be much appreciated!

**Edit**

After the assistance of Ankit, tried the following (his answer):

```
declare @id int
declare @maxid int

set @id = 1
select @maxid = max(idJCMaster) from _btblJCMaster

declare @IDseq table    (id int)

while @id < @maxid --whatever you max is
begin
    insert into @IDseq values(@id)

    set @id = @id + 1
end

select 
    s.id
,   (SELECT MAX(dStartDate)
            FROM _btblJCMaster
            WHERE id >= t1.idJCMaster) dStartDate
from        @IDseq s 
left join   _btblJCMaster t1 on s.id = t1.idJCMaster
```

But I still receive `NULLS`.

I then proceeded to try his first answer, by altering the `LAG` function a bit and also adding `LEAD`, with 3 CTE's, but I still get `NULLS`:

```
declare @id int
declare @maxid int

set @id = 1
select @maxid = max(idJCMaster) from _btblJCMaster

declare @IDseq table    (id int)

while @id < @maxid --whatever you max is
begin
    insert into @IDseq values(@id)

    set @id = @id + 1
end


;with cte (id, dStartDate, idJCMaster)
as
(
select 
    s.id
,   ISNULL(dStartDate, isnull(LAG(dStartDate) OVER(order by s.id),LEAD(dStartDate) OVER(order by s.id)))
,   IdJCMaster
from        @IDseq s 
left join   _btblJCMaster t1 on s.id = t1.idJCMaster
)
,   cte2 (id,dStartDate, idJCMaster)
as
(
select
    id
,   isnull(dStartDate,LAG(dStartDate) OVER(order by id))
,   idJCMaster
from    cte
)
,   cte3 (id,dStartDate, idJCMaster)
as
(
select
    id
,   isnull(dStartDate,LEAD(dStartDate) OVER(order by id))
,   idJCMaster
from    cte2
)

select
    id
,   isnull(dStartDate,LAG(dStartDate) OVER(order by id))
from    cte3
where   idJCMaster is null
```

Is there no other easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something along this:

First we need a *mockup table* to simulate your issue. Please provide this yourself in your next question. It is always best to provide a *self-running, stand-alone* sample including DDL, INSERT and your own attempt. Such a simuation is called [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean).

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id INT,  dStartDate DATE);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (126,'2010-04-22 00:00:00.000')
,(127,NULL)
,(128,'2010-04-29 00:00:00.000')
,(129,'2010-05-03 00:00:00.000')
,(130,NULL)
,(131,NULL)
,(132,NULL)
,(133,'2010-04-29 00:00:00.000')
,(134,NULL)
,(135,NULL)
,(136,'2010-04-29 00:00:00.000')
,(137,NULL)
,(138,NULL)
,(139,'2010-04-29 00:00:00.000')
,(140,NULL)
,(141,'2010-04-29 00:00:00.000')
,(142,'2010-04-29 00:00:00.000')
,(143,NULL)
,(144,NULL);
```

--The query

```
WITH cte AS(SELECT id,dStartDate FROM @tbl WHERE dStartDate IS NOT NULL)
SELECT t.id 
      ,A.gaplessStartDate
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 cte.dStartDate 
            FROM cte 
            WHERE cte.id<=t.id 
            ORDER BY cte.id DESC) A(gaplessStartDate);
```

The idea in short:

We use a CTE first to get a set with non-null rows only.
Now we can use `APPLY` to get the fitting row along with the id by calling the top-most of the **smaller ids** sorted in descending order.

The approach is sort of a [*triangle JOIN* (Jeff Moden wrote a great article on this)](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hidden-rbar-triangular-joins). Any row will need a correlated sub-query with an ORDER BY action.

Hint: With larger set this might be faster if you use an indexed temp table instead of the CTE.

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo! Regarding *It is always best to provide a self-running, stand-alone sample including DDL, INSERT and your own attempt* I will definitely provide it next time :-) This script works like a charm, however, may I request an alteration to only show id's that are `NULL`, that way, you only see the dates that for those that do not exist? If you know what I mean?

Comment: @Birel If I get this correctly, it should be enough to add `WHERE t.dStartDate IS NULL` as last line.

Answer (score 1):

You may try below query -

```
SELECT id, (SELECT MAX(dStartDate)
            FROM YOUR_TABLE
            WHERE id >= t1.id) dStartDate
FROM YOUR_TABLE t1;
```

Comment: Thank you Ankit, I ran it and got this message : `The function 'LAG' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.` I then added the order by like this : `ISNULL(dStartDate, LAG(dStartDate) OVER(order by s.id))` and it's now working.

However some of the records are still showing nulls, due to more than 3 records being missing at a time... Anyway around this?

Comment: Ohhh. I forgot that caluse. Let me correct that also.

Comment: @Birel, Please try now.

Comment: Ankit, tried you're edit - no success, please see edit I made to my question...

Comment: @AnkitBajpai If you look at the sample data closely, you'll find, that the ids are constantly increasing, but the date is not. Using `MAX(dStartdate)` will not lead to the needed result...

Comment: Hmmm. I have just realised it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Shnugo for your assistance!

With your help, the following script gives me exactly what I required that works on my data set:

```
declare @id int
declare @maxid int

set @id = 1
select @maxid = max(idJCMaster) from _btblJCMaster

declare @IDseq table    (id int)

while @id < @maxid --whatever you max is
begin
    insert into @IDseq values(@id)

    set @id = @id + 1
end

;with source (id,dStartDate)
as
(
select 
    s.id
,   dStartDate
from        @IDseq s 
left join   _btblJCMaster t1 on s.id = t1.idJCMaster
)
, cte AS(SELECT id,dStartDate FROM source WHERE dStartDate IS NOT NULL)
SELECT t.id 
      ,A.gaplessStartDate
FROM source t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 cte.dStartDate 
            FROM cte 
            WHERE cte.id<=t.id 
            ORDER BY cte.id DESC) A(gaplessStartDate)
WHERE t.dStartDate IS NULL
order by id
```

This is just for other viewers to use, should you require it.